# How can I raise this exception properly?

Tags: python, exception, python-unittest

How can I raise this exception properly?

```py
import unittest

def second_digit_value4(n): return True if n % 10 == 4 else False

class DigitValue4(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_last_digit_value4(self):
        self.assertEqual(second_digit_value4(14), True)
        self.assertFalse(second_digit_value4(22), False)

        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            second_digit_value4(23)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Why *would* you raise a ValueError there?

Comment: I am a complete rookie this is just for practice. This is an exercise on which I needed to make sure that the second digit was equal to 4. The purpose of creating a Value error is for practice.

Comment: Practice with something that *should* raise an exception, then.

Comment: @YoshuaVillar: The problem here is that there is no reason why `22` should return `False` while `23` dies with a `ValueError`. You haven't described a rule distinguishing those two cases, just a rule describing when it should return `True`.

Comment: Why would it ever return `ValueError`? That's used when the parameter has the correct type, but an invalid value. But what number is invalid for testing the last digit?

Comment: `TypeError` would make more sense. It should check that the argument is an integer, and raise `TypeError` if it isn't.

Comment: @Barmar: Given the name `second_digit_value4` and the fact that it tests the low digit, it seems like it implicitly requires a value in `range(10, 100)`, so a `ValueError` could reasonably be raised when that condition is violated. Or even with a better name to encompass "testing one's place", the means of testing doesn't make sense for negative values (`-11 % 10`  is `9`, which isn't testing the "low digit"), so negative numbers being a `ValueError` could make sense (assuming using `abs` to normalize isn't okay for whatever reason). But yeah, the whole premise here is odd.

Answer (score 0):

Since the function only works correctly for positive numbers with 2 digits, it should check that the parameter is between 10 and 99. Then you should test it with a number outside that range.

```
import unittest

def second_digit_value4(n): 
    if 10 <= n <= 99:
        return n % 10 == 4
    raise ValueError("number must be 2 digits")

class DigitValue4(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_last_digit_value4(self):
        self.assertEqual(second_digit_value4(14), True)
        self.assertFalse(second_digit_value4(22), False)

        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            second_digit_value4(123)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: So to use raise value error in the test I need to have it present on the function?

Comment: The whole point of `assertRaises` is to check if the exception is raised in the tested code, otherwise why would you need it?

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests don't need to throw an error. They check if things are true or false and depending on the result, the test either passes or it fails.

Modify your test to:

```
assertTrue(second_digit_value4(14), 'second_digit_value4 failed on 14')
assertFalse(second_digit_value4(22), 'second_digit_value4 failed on 22')
```

Exceptions are used to handle "unexpected" circumstances. You can modify your function to:

```
def second_digit_value4(n): 
if not n.isnumeric():
    raise ValueError("value must be a number")
if 10 <= n <= 99:
    return n % 10 == 4
else:
    raise ValueError("value out of range")
```

Then to check if the exception is thrown:

```
def test1(self):
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
       second_digit_value4('This is NaN')
```

You can add another test for the out of range exception.

What this does is it allows your function to return without performing the operation and returning the result, which would be impossible on that input.

Alternatively you can just return a NaN and not throw.

Comment: But they can also test that an exception is raised when it's supposed to. That's what they're asking about.